# How to scale group inside Jetpack Compose Vector

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am making a country map in Jetpack compose using vector `Group`s and `Path`s for each region in the map. I want to animate the scale of a specific region but am struggling to set the correct `pivotX` and `pivotY` for the `Group` belonging to the correct region that should animate larger and smaller, resulting in the region also moving in the x and y direction. My code is as follows:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.animation.core.EaseInOut
import androidx.compose.animation.core.RepeatMode
import androidx.compose.animation.core.animateFloat
import androidx.compose.animation.core.infiniteRepeatable
import androidx.compose.animation.core.rememberInfiniteTransition
import androidx.compose.animation.core.tween
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SolidColor
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.Group
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.Path
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathNode
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.PathParser
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.vector.rememberVectorPainter
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

typealias Province = String

object Netherlands {
    val PathMap = mapOf<Province, List<List<PathNode>>>(
        "Overijssel" to listOf(
            PathParser().parsePathString(
                "m144.01 59.386-1.162 0.77493-0.77463 0.77492h-1.162-0.38732l0.38732 0.77492v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746-0.77463 0.38746v-0.77492l-1.162 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.77492v-0.77492l-0.77464 0.38746v0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746v0.38746h-0.77463l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38732 0.38747h-0.38731v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38747h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77493 0.38731 0.77492 0.77464 0.77492v0.38746h0.77463 0.77463l0.38732 0.38746 1.1619 0.38747 0.38732 0.77492 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.77463 0.77492 0.38732 1.1624 0.77463 1.5498v0.38746h0.38732l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.38747v0.38746 0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746-0.77463 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l0.77463 0.38746h0.38732l0.77463 0.38747 0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.77463l0.38732 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746-1.1619 0.77492h-0.38732l-1.162 0.38747v0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.77464 0.38746-0.77463-0.77492-3.0985 0.77492-0.38731 0.38746v0.77492 0.38746 0.38747l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-1.5493-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 0.38732 0.38747v0.38746 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.77492 0.77492l0.77463-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746 0.77463 1.1624 0.38732 0.77492 0.77463 1.1624v0.77493l0.77463-0.38747 0.77463-0.77492v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 2.3239-2.3248h0.38732 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.77464 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746 1.162 0.38746 0.38732 0.38747v0.38746l0.38731 1.1624v0.77492l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38747v0.77492l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746 0.77492l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732v0.38747 0.38746 0.77492h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.77463 0.38746h-0.77464v0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746l0.38731 0.38747h0.38732l0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v0.77492 0.77492 0.77493h-0.38732v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731v0.38746 1.1624h0.38732 0.38732 0.38731v0.38746 0.38746h0.38732v1.1624l0.77463 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.38747h0.38731 0.38732 0.38731v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.77492h0.38731 0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.38746h0.38732v0.38746h0.77463 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.38732 0.77463 0.38732l0.38731 0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38732v0.38746h1.1619v-0.38746h0.77464v-0.77492h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.77463 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.77464 0.38731v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.77492 1.1619 0.77492v0.77493h0.38732v0.38746h0.77463v0.77492l0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.38732l1.9366 0.38746 1.5493-0.38746h0.38732l0.77463 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746 0.77464 0.77493v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38747 0.38732-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746v0.38747l0.38732-0.77493h0.38731l1.162 0.77493v0.38746 0.38746 1.1624l-0.77463 1.1624h0.77463 0.38732l1.5493 0.77492h0.38732 2.3239 3.0985 1.162l0.38731-0.38746 0.77464-0.77493v-0.38746l0.38731-1.9373h0.38732v-0.38746l1.162-0.77493v-0.38746l1.1619-0.38746h1.162l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38747l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.38732 0.77463l1.1619-0.77492v-0.38746l-1.1619-1.5498-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77492h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38747-0.38746-0.38746l0.38731-1.1624v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38747-0.38746l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.77463-1.1624v-1.9373l-0.77463-1.5498v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731-0.77492-0.38732-0.77492-0.77463-0.77493v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492v-0.77492l-0.38731-0.77492v-0.38747h-0.38732-0.38732l-0.38731 0.77493-0.38732 1.1624-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732l-1.9366-0.38746-0.77463-0.38746-1.162-0.38746h-0.77463l0.38732-0.77492h-0.77463-1.162-2.3239-0.77463l-0.38731-0.38746-1.5493-0.77493-0.38731-0.38746-0.77464-0.38746 0.38732-3.0997-0.77463-1.1624-0.77463-1.5498h0.38731l0.77463 0.38746h0.77464l0.38731-1.1624h0.77463l0.77464 0.38746 0.38731-0.38746-2.3239-1.9373v-0.77492l0.38731-1.5498v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38747-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746h-0.77463l-3.8732-1.9373v0.38746h-0.38731l-1.162 0.38746h-1.5493l-1.9366 1.9373 0.38731 2.3248v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732-0.77463l-0.77463-0.77493v0.38747l-0.77463 0.77492-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38747h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38747v0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77493l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38747h0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746-1.162-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.77463-1.1624v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492-0.38732-0.77493-0.38731-0.77492v-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 1.162-0.38746 0.38731-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.77493 0.38732-0.38746 0.38731-0.77492h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.77492-3.0985-3.0997v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.77493zm2.7112 52.695v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746z"
            ).toNodes()
        ),
        "Gelderland" to listOf(
            PathParser().parsePathString(
                "m132.01 87.283-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38731 1.1624-0.38732 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746l-0.38732 0.77493v0.38746 0.38746l-0.38731-0.38746v0.77492h-0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38731 0.77492v0.38746h0.38731v0.38746h-0.38731l0.38731 0.38746-0.77463 0.77493-1.9366 1.9373-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38747h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731l-0.77463 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746-0.77463 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77493v0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v0.38746 0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746l-0.77463 0.38747-0.77463 0.77492v0.38746l-0.38732 0.77492v0.77492l-0.38732 0.77493v0.38746l-0.38731 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746h-1.5493-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77492-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731 0.38746-1.162 0.38747h-0.77463l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.77463l-0.38732 1.9373v0.38746l0.77464 0.38746v-0.38746l1.5493 1.1624v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746 0.38746 1.1624l0.38732 0.38746h1.9366v0.38746h-0.38732l0.38732 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732v0.77492h0.77463v0.38747 0.38746h-0.77463v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746v0.77493 0.38746l-0.77464 0.77492h-0.38731v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746 0.77464 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38747 1.162-0.38746 0.38732 0.77493v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746 1.9373h0.77463v0.38746h-0.38732l1.162 0.77492v1.1624 0.38746 0.38746 0.38746l0.77463 0.77492h0.38732v0.38746l0.38731 0.77493v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746 0.38732 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746l-0.38732 0.38747-0.77463 0.38746-0.77463-0.38746-1.162-0.38747-0.77463-0.38746-0.38732-0.77492h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-1.162l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77492h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463-0.38746-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.77464-0.77492h-1.1619-0.38732l-0.77463-0.77492-0.77463-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732v0.77492l-0.38731 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746-0.38732 0.77492-0.38731 1.1624-0.77463 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746h0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746-0.38732 0.77492h-0.38731v0.38747l-0.38732 1.1624-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732-0.77463-0.38732v0.77492l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732-0.38731v0.38747 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-1.162 0.38746-0.38731-0.38746-0.77463 0.38746-0.38732-0.38746v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732l0.38732 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.77463l-0.38732 1.5498v0.38746h-0.77463v0.38746 0.38746h0.38732l0.38731 0.38746 0.77464 0.38746 0.38731 0.38747h0.38732v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746h0.38732v0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38731l0.77464 0.77492 1.1619 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746 0.38747l0.38732 0.38746-0.77463 0.77492h-0.38732v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.77463 0.77463 0.38732 0.77463 0.38732 0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746 0.77464 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746 0.77463-0.77492h0.77464l0.77463 0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l0.77464-0.38746 1.9366-0.77492v-0.38746h0.38731v-0.77493-0.77492l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.77463-1.1624 0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.77463 0.77463l0.38732-0.38746 0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731 0.77463 0.38732 0.38731l0.77464 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.77463l0.38732 0.38746v0.77492l1.1619 1.1624h0.38732 0.38732l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732v0.77492h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746v0.38747l0.38732 0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.77463 0.38732l1.162-0.38746h0.38731 1.162 0.77463 0.38732 0.38731v-0.38747-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38746 0.38731-0.38746h0.77464 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.38747v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746h0.38731v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.77493v-0.38746h-0.38732v-0.77492h0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38747l-0.77463-0.77492h-0.38732-0.38732v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l-0.77464-0.38746 0.77464-1.1624h0.38731v0.38747h0.77463 0.38732l0.77463-0.38747h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746 0.77464-0.77492h0.38731l-0.38731-0.38746 0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746 1.162 1.1624h0.38731 0.38732l1.5493 0.38746h1.162l0.38732 0.38746v-0.77492-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l-0.77464-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38747-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492-0.38731-0.38746h-0.77464-0.38731l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732l0.38732 0.38746 1.5493-0.77492 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.77463 0.38746v0.38746h-0.77463l0.77463 0.77492 0.38731 0.38746 0.77464 0.38747h0.77463v-0.38747h0.77463l0.38732 0.38747h0.38731v-0.38747h0.38732v-0.38746l0.38731 0.38746 1.162 0.38747v0.38746l0.38732 0.77492v0.38746l0.77463-0.38746h0.77463 0.38732l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732l0.38732 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38731l0.77464 0.38747h0.38731l-0.38731-0.77493 0.38731 0.38746-0.38731-0.77492v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.77493l0.77464 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38747h0.38731v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 0.38732 0.77492h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731-0.38746 1.162-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38747h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746h0.38732 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v0.38746h0.38732l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746 1.9366-0.77492h0.38731 0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.38747 0.77463-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v0.38746h0.38732 0.38732v0.38746l1.1619 1.1624 0.77464-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38747h0.38731v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l0.77463-1.1624 0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38747-1.1624l0.77464-0.38746h0.77463l0.38731-0.77492-0.38731-0.38746v-0.77493-0.38746l-1.162-0.38746h0.38732l-2.3239-1.5498-0.38732-0.38747-0.38731-0.77492-1.9366-0.77492h-1.5493v-0.38746-0.77492-0.38747l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746h1.162l1.5493-0.77492v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38747h0.38732v-0.38746l0.38731-1.5498h-2.3239-0.38732l-1.5493-0.77492h-0.38732-0.77463l0.77463-1.1624v-1.1624-0.38746-0.38746l-1.162-0.77493h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.77493v-0.38747l-0.38731-0.38746-0.38732 0.38746-0.38731 0.38747v0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38747 0.38732-0.38746-0.77463-0.38746h-0.38732l-1.5493 0.38746-1.9366-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.38746-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77492h-0.77463v-0.38746h-0.38732v-0.77493l-1.1619-0.77492-0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38731-0.77464-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.77463l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v0.77492h-0.77464v0.38746h-1.1619v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732-0.77463-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732v0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731-0.77463v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38747v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v-1.1624h-0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38732v-1.1624-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.77493-0.77492-0.77492h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38747v-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746h0.77464l0.77463-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.77492-0.38746-0.38747h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746v-0.77492-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746v-0.77492l-0.38731-0.38747-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77492l-0.38731-1.1624v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38747-1.162-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.77464-0.77492h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746-1.5493 1.5498-0.38732 0.38746-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746-0.77463 0.38747v-0.77493l-0.77463-1.1624-0.38732-0.77492-0.77463-1.1624-0.38732-0.38746zm-12.781 13.949-0.77463-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732z"
            ).toNodes()
        ),
        "Utrecht" to listOf(
            PathParser().parsePathString(
                "m87.466 105.88v0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746 0.38747l-0.77464-0.38747v0.38747l-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38732l-0.77463-0.38746-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746-0.38731 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v0.38747l-0.38732-0.38747h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38747-0.77464 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38731v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.77493 0.38746h0.38732v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.77463l0.38732 0.38746 1.5493 1.1624-1.1619 0.38746v1.5498h-0.38732-0.38732-0.77463-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.77464l-0.77463 0.77493h0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v0.38746l1.5493 0.77492 0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732v1.1624l0.38732 1.1624v0.38746h0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h0.77463 1.5493l-0.77464 0.77493h-0.38731l-1.162 0.77492-0.38732 1.1624-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38747 0.38731 0.77492h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746h0.38732 0.38732 0.38731 0.38732l0.38731 1.1624h-0.38731l-1.5493 0.38746 0.38732 0.38746 0.38732 0.77493 0.38731 0.77492 0.38732 0.38746 0.77463 0.77492v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746v0.77493 0.38746h0.38731 0.77463 0.38732l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746h0.38732l-0.00974-0.41037 0.3 0.3 0.4 1.6 0.2-0.3 0.2-0.2 0.4 1.5 0.4 0.2v0.3l0.4 0.2v1l1.1-0.5v0.6l0.1 0.5v0.7l-0.1 0.3 0.1 0.3 1.4-0.7-0.1 0.9 0.3 0.9-0.05516 0.55959 1.162-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38747h0.38731 0.38732 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v-0.77492h0.38732 0.77463 0.38732v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-1.1624v-0.38747h0.38731l0.38732-0.77492 0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732l1.162-1.1624 0.38731-1.1624 0.38732-0.77492 0.77463 0.77492h0.38732 0.38731l0.77463-0.77492v-0.77492h0.38732 0.38732l0.77463 0.38746 0.77463 0.77492h0.38732 1.1619l0.77464 0.77492h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.77463 0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746h0.38732l0.77463-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731 0.38746h1.162 0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.77463 0.38746h0.38732l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.77492 0.77463 0.38746 1.162 0.38747 0.77463 0.38746 0.77463-0.38746 0.38732-0.38747v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.77493v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-1.1624l-1.162-0.77492h0.38732v-0.38746h-0.77463v-1.9373-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77493-1.162 0.38746 0.38732 0.38747v0.38746 0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77492h-0.38732-0.38731l-0.77464-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38731l0.77464-0.77492v-0.38746-0.77493l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746h0.77463v-0.38746-0.38747h-0.77463v-0.77492h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746h-1.9366l-0.38732-0.38746v-1.1624-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l-1.5493-1.1624v0.38746l-0.77464-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-1.9373-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.38747-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.77463l-0.38732-0.38746h-1.5493l-0.77464-0.38746-1.1619 2.3248v0.38747 0.38746l-0.38732 0.77492-0.38732 1.1624-0.38731 0.77492v0.77493l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l-0.77463 1.5498h-0.77463-0.38732-0.38731l-2.3239-0.38746h-0.38731l-1.9366 0.77493-1.5493 0.38746v-1.5498h-0.38731v-0.77492-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746h0.77464v-0.38746-0.38747-0.77492-0.77492h0.38731l0.77463-0.38746-0.77463-0.38746v-0.77492-0.38747h-0.38731v0.38747l-0.38732-0.38747-0.38732-1.1624v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38732v-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732v-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38732 0.38746v-1.5498h-0.38731-0.38732z"
            ).toNodes()
        ),
          "Noord-Holland" to listOf(
            PathParser().parsePathString("m71.973 49.699-0.77464 0.38746-0.38731 0.38747h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38747-0.38746-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.38732l1.162-0.38746h0.77463v0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746z")
                .toNodes(),
            PathParser().parsePathString(
                "m73.909 50.474-0.77463 1.1624v0.38746 0.38746 0.77492l-0.38731 1.1624v1.1624 1.5498l-0.77463 2.3248-0.38732 2.3248-0.77463 2.3248v0.77492h-0.38732v0.77492l-0.77463 1.5498v0.77492l-0.77463 2.3248v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746 0.38746 1.1624l-0.38732 1.5498v0.77492 0.77493l-0.38731 1.5498v0.77492 0.38747 0.77492l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38732 2.7122-0.38731 3.4872-0.38732 1.9373-0.38731 0.77492-0.77464 1.5498-0.38731 1.1624 0.77463-0.38746h0.38732l0.77463-0.38747 0.38731 0.38747h-0.38731v0.38746h-0.77463l-0.38732 0.38746h0.77463v0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746v0.77492l0.38732 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746v0.77493l-0.38731 0.77492-0.38732 1.5498-0.38732 1.1624-0.77463 1.9373-1.5493 3.0997 2.7112 1.1624 1.162 0.38746v-0.77492l0.38731 0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.77463 0.38746-0.38731 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746v0.77492h-0.38731v0.38747 0.38746l-1.162 1.1624v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746 0.77493l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463 0.38746h1.162 0.38732 0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.38731l0.77464-0.77492 1.1619 0.38746-0.38731 1.1624 0.77463 0.77493 0.38731-0.77493h0.38732 0.77463l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38732 0.38731 0.38732 0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l0.77464-0.38746 0.38731-0.38747h0.38732 0.38731l0.38732 0.38747v-0.38747h0.38732 0.38731v-0.38746l0.77463-0.77492-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746 0.77463 0.38746h0.38732 0.38732 0.38731v-0.38746l0.77463-0.38746v-0.38747l0.77464 0.38747v-0.38747-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731v1.5498l0.38732-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732v0.38746l0.38732 1.1624 0.38732 0.38747v-0.38747h0.38731v0.38747 0.77492l0.77463 0.38746-0.77463 0.38746h-0.38731v0.77492 0.77492 0.38747 0.38746h-0.77464l0.38732 0.38746h0.38732v0.38746 0.77492h0.38731v1.5498l1.5493-0.38746 1.9366-0.77493h0.38731l2.3239 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.77463l1.162-2.3248v-0.77493l0.38731-0.77492 0.38732-1.1624 0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746-0.38747l1.1619-2.3248 0.77464 0.38746h1.5493l-0.77463-0.77492v-0.38747l0.38731-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732-1.5493l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.77463-0.77492-0.38732-0.77492h-0.38731v-0.38747h-0.77463-0.38732l-0.38732-0.77492h-1.1619-0.38732-0.38732l-0.77463 0.38746-0.38731-0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38747h0.38731 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746-1.1619-0.77492v-0.38746l0.77463 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732l0.38732-0.38746v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746 0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746v-0.77492l0.77463-0.77493 0.38732-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l0.77463-0.77492h-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38747v0.38747l-0.77463-0.38747v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746-0.38731-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.77463v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38747v-0.38746-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732-0.77492h-0.38732v-0.77493h-0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l-0.77463-1.1624v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38746v-0.77492l-0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.38747 0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-0.77492-0.38747h0.38732v-0.38746h0.38732l0.38731-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38731l0.77464 0.77492h0.38731l0.38732 0.38747v0.38746h0.77463 0.38732 0.38731l1.162-1.1624h0.38731 0.77464v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.38746v-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746v-0.77493-0.38746l0.38731-0.77492h0.38732 0.38731 0.38732l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731l-0.38731-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 0.38731-0.38747-0.77463-0.77492v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746-0.38747h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-0.77463-0.38746h-1.162-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.77463-0.38732l-0.38732 0.77492-0.38731 0.38746v0.38747l-0.38732-0.38747h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38731l-0.77464-0.77492-0.77463-0.77492 0.38732-0.77492h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l0.77463-5.8119-0.77463-1.1624-1.162-2.3248v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38747-1.162-2.3248h-0.38732v-0.77493l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.77463l-0.77463 0.77493v0.38746l-0.77464 1.1624h-0.38731l-0.77463 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746-1.5493 0.77493-0.38732-0.38746-1.162-0.77493h-0.38731l-1.162-0.77492-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.38746-0.38732-0.77492v-0.77493-0.77492l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.77463-0.77463-0.38732-0.38732zm3.4858 0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38732l0.38732 0.38746zm12.007 2.3248 0.38732 0.38747v-0.77493h-0.38732v0.38746zm-3.4858 47.27v0.38747h0.38731l-0.38731-0.38747zm6.5844-8.5241v0.38746 0.38746l-0.38732 0.77492h0.38732l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746-0.77463-0.77492zm10.458 13.561v0.38746h0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746z"
            ).toNodes(),
            PathParser().parsePathString("m80.494 43.887-1.162 1.1624h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732l-1.162 1.5498v0.38746 0.38747h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38747-0.77463-0.38746h-0.38731l1.1619 1.1624h0.38732-0.77463v0.38746h-0.77463-0.38732 0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746-0.77492l-0.38731-1.5498v-0.77492-0.38746l0.38731-1.1624v-0.38746l0.38732-1.1624 0.38731-1.1624 0.38732-1.1624 0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-1.1624 0.77463-1.5498 1.162-1.1624v0.38746 0.38746l0.38731-0.38746 0.77464-0.77492h0.38731v0.38746-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746l-0.38732 0.38746-0.77463 0.38746 1.162-2.3248 0.38731-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38732l0.77463 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731-0.38731v0.38746l0.77463 0.77493 0.77463 1.1624v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746v2.3248 1.1624 0.38746l-0.38732 0.77493h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746v0.77492l-0.77463 0.77492v0.38746z")
                .toNodes(),
            PathParser().parsePathString("m95.986 47.762-5.4224 4.6495-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746h0.77463l5.4224-4.6495z")
                .toNodes()
        ),
        // more regions
    )
}

@Composable
fun Netherlands(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val vectorPainter = rememberVectorPainter(
        defaultWidth = 200.dp,
        defaultHeight = 236.dp,
        viewportHeight = 236f,
        viewportWidth = 200f,
        autoMirror = false
    ) { _, _ ->
        val duration = 3000
        val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")
        val scale by transition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 1.0f,
            targetValue = 1.2f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                tween(duration, easing = EaseInOut),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            ), label = "scaleTransition"
        )
        for (entry in Netherlands.PathMap) {
            val (province, paths) = entry
            Group(
                name = province,
                scaleX = if (shouldScaleProvince(province)) scale else 1.0f,
                scaleY = if (shouldScaleProvince(province)) scale else 1.0f,
                pivotX = ??,
                pivotY = ??
            ) {
                for (path in paths) {
                    Path(
                        stroke = SolidColor(Color.White),
                        pathData = path,
                        fill = SolidColor(Color.Black),
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    Image(
        modifier = modifier,
        painter = vectorPainter,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

As I understand it, the default `pivotX` and `pivotY` are in the top left corner, but I should set those to the center of the `Group` but how do I calculate this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get size from paths by creating a map that has `Path` as

Result

[image]

```
typealias Province = String

object Netherlands {
    val PathParserMap = mapOf<Province, List<PathParser>>(
        "Overijssel" to listOf(
            PathParser().parsePathString(
                "m144.01 59.386-1.162 0.77493-0.77463 0.77492h-1.162-0.38732l0.38732 0.77492v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746-0.77463 0.38746v-0.77492l-1.162 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746-0.38731-0.77492v-0.77492l-0.77464 0.38746v0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746v0.38746h-0.77463l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38732 0.38747h-0.38731v0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38747h-0.38732l-0.77463 0.77493 0.38731 0.77492 0.77464 0.77492v0.38746h0.77463 0.77463l0.38732 0.38746 1.1619 0.38747 0.38732 0.77492 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.77463 0.77492 0.38732 1.1624 0.77463 1.5498v0.38746h0.38732l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.38747v0.38746 0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746-0.77463 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746h0.38731v-0.38746l0.77463 0.38746h0.38732l0.77463 0.38747 0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.77463l0.38732 0.77492-0.38732 0.38746-1.1619 0.77492h-0.38732l-1.162 0.38747v0.38746l-0.77463 0.38746h-0.38731l-0.77464 0.38746-0.77463-0.77492-3.0985 0.77492-0.38731 0.38746v0.77492 0.38746 0.38747l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-1.5493-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731 0.38732v0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 0.38732 0.38747v0.38746 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746v0.77492 0.77492l0.77463-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746 0.77463 1.1624 0.38732 0.77492 0.77463 1.1624v0.77493l0.77463-0.38747 0.77463-0.77492v0.38746l0.38732 0.38746 2.3239-2.3248h0.38732 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746 0.38732 0.38746h0.38731l0.77464 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746l0.38731 0.38746 1.162 0.38746 0.38732 0.38747v0.38746l0.38731 1.1624v0.77492l0.38732 0.38746 0.38731 0.38747v0.77492l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746 0.77492l0.38731 0.38746h0.38732v0.38747 0.38746 0.77492h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.77463 0.38746h-0.77464v0.38746h-0.38731v0.38746l0.38731 0.38747h0.38732l0.38732 0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732 0.38746h-0.38731v0.77492 0.77492 0.77493h-0.38732v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731v0.38746 1.1624h0.38732 0.38732 0.38731v0.38746 0.38746h0.38732v1.1624l0.77463 0.77492v0.38746 0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.38747h0.38731 0.38732 0.38731v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732 0.38746v0.38746l0.38732 0.77492h0.38731 0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.38746h0.38732v0.38746h0.77463 0.38731l0.38732 0.38746v-0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.38732 0.77463 0.38732l0.38731 0.38746 0.38732-0.38746h0.38731 0.38732 0.38732v0.38746h1.1619v-0.38746h0.77464v-0.77492h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746h0.77463 0.38732l0.38731-0.38746v0.38746h0.38732 0.38731 0.77464 0.38731v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732 0.77492 1.1619 0.77492v0.77493h0.38732v0.38746h0.77463v0.77492l0.38732 0.38746v0.38746h0.38731l0.38732 0.38746 0.77463-0.38746h0.38732l1.9366 0.38746 1.5493-0.38746h0.38732l0.77463 0.38746-0.38732 0.38746 0.77464 0.77493v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38747 0.38732-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746v0.38747l0.38732-0.77493h0.38731l1.162 0.77493v0.38746 0.38746 1.1624l-0.77463 1.1624h0.77463 0.38732l1.5493 0.77492h0.38732 2.3239 3.0985 1.162l0.38731-0.38746 0.77464-0.77493v-0.38746l0.38731-1.9373h0.38732v-0.38746l1.162-0.77493v-0.38746l1.1619-0.38746h1.162l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.38731-0.38746v-0.38747l0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746 0.77463-0.38746 0.38731 0.38746h0.38732 0.38732 0.77463l1.1619-0.77492v-0.38746l-1.1619-1.5498-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77492h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38747-0.38746-0.38746l0.38731-1.1624v-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746h0.38731v-0.38747-0.38746l0.38732-0.77492v-0.38746l0.77463-1.1624v-1.9373l-0.77463-1.5498v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731-0.77492-0.38732-0.77492-0.77463-0.77493v-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492v-0.77492l-0.38731-0.77492v-0.38747h-0.38732-0.38732l-0.38731 0.77493-0.38732 1.1624-0.77463 0.38746v0.38746h-0.38732l-1.9366-0.38746-0.77463-0.38746-1.162-0.38746h-0.77463l0.38732-0.77492h-0.77463-1.162-2.3239-0.77463l-0.38731-0.38746-1.5493-0.77493-0.38731-0.38746-0.77464-0.38746 0.38732-3.0997-0.77463-1.1624-0.77463-1.5498h0.38731l0.77463 0.38746h0.77464l0.38731-1.1624h0.77463l0.77464 0.38746 0.38731-0.38746-2.3239-1.9373v-0.77492l0.38731-1.5498v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.38747-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746-0.38746-0.38746l0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746h-0.77463l-3.8732-1.9373v0.38746h-0.38731l-1.162 0.38746h-1.5493l-1.9366 1.9373 0.38731 2.3248v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38732-0.77463l-0.77463-0.77493v0.38747l-0.77463 0.77492-0.38732-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38747h-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38747v0.38746h-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.77493l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38746-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38731v-0.38747h0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746h-0.38732-0.38732-0.38731v-0.38746h-0.38732v0.38746h-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732l-0.38731-0.38746v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732v-0.38746h-0.38732-0.38731-0.38732l-0.38731 0.38746v0.38746l-0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.38731 0.38746 0.38731 0.38746-1.162-0.38746 0.38732-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.77463-0.38746v-0.38746l-0.77463-1.1624v-0.38746-0.38746l-0.38732-0.77492-0.38732-0.77493-0.38731-0.77492v-0.38746h0.38731l0.38732-0.38746 1.162-0.38746 0.38731-0.38746h0.38732v-0.38746l0.77463-0.77493 0.38732-0.38746 0.38731-0.77492h-0.38731l-0.38732-0.77492-3.0985-3.0997v-0.38746l-0.38731-0.77493zm2.7112 52.695v0.38746 0.38746l0.38732-0.38746-0.38732-0.38746z"
            )
        ),
        // Rest of the provinces
    )

    val PathNodeMap: Map<Province, List<List<PathNode>>> =
        PathParserMap.mapValues { entry: Map.Entry<Province, List<PathParser>> ->
            entry.value.map {
                it.toNodes().toList()
            }
        }

    val PathMap: Map<Province, List<Path>> =
        PathParserMap.mapValues { entry: Map.Entry<Province, List<PathParser>> ->
            entry.value.map {
                it.toPath()
            }
        }

}
```

You can get center of bounds of any Path with

```
val pathList = Netherlands.PathMap[province]
val pathForSize = Path()
pathList?.forEach {
    pathForSize.addPath(it)
}

val center = pathForSize.getBounds().center
```

Full implementation

```
@Composable
fun Netherlands(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, selecetedIndex: Int) {

    val vectorPainter = rememberVectorPainter(
        defaultWidth = 200.dp,
        defaultHeight = 236.dp,
        viewportHeight = 236f,
        viewportWidth = 200f,
        autoMirror = false
    ) { _, _ ->
        val duration = 3000
        val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "transition")
        val scale by transition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 1.0f,
            targetValue = 1.4f,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                tween(duration, easing = EaseInOut),
                repeatMode = RepeatMode.Reverse
            ), label = "scaleTransition"
        )

        var index = 0
        for (entry in Netherlands.PathNodeMap) {
            val (province, paths) = entry

            val pathList = Netherlands.PathMap[province]
            val pathForSize = Path()
            pathList?.forEach {
                pathForSize.addPath(it)
            }

            val center = pathForSize.getBounds().center

            Group(
                name = province,
                scaleX = if (index == selecetedIndex) scale else 1.0f,
                scaleY = if (index == selecetedIndex) scale else 1.0f,
                pivotX = center.x,
                pivotY = center.y
            ) {
                for (path in paths) {
                    Path(
                        stroke = SolidColor(Color.White),
                        pathData = path,
                        fill = SolidColor(if (index == selecetedIndex) Color.Red else Color.Black),
                    )
                }
            }

            index++
        }
    }
    Image(
        modifier = modifier,
        painter = vectorPainter,
        contentDescription = null
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `Path.getBounds().center` was the API I was looking for! How would you implement a click listener on the individual region?

Comment: You can't add click listener for individual regions but check if touch position is inside that region with a detectTap or custom gesture that returns Offset. But you probably need to take actual size of regions to viewport size to determine touch position on Composable corresponds in drawable. When i have time i will answer this question as Q&A. You can check this answer with paths. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217578/how-can-i-determine-whether-a-2d-point-is-within-a-polygon?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77228982/is-it-possible-to-attach-event-handlers-like-onclick-drag-to-the-content-being/77229242#77229242 This one is for detecting touch on circles instead of `Path`s.

Comment: Thanks for the links! If you have time i'd be interested in your specific implementation for my case.

Comment: @NielsMasdorp answered your question here. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77579871/5457853